# How long do title revocation penalties last?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I want to revoke a couple of vassal titles and would like to spread out the penalties over a longer period of time. How long does an individual revocation penalty last for, and does the game track each revocation individually or simply just reset the timer every time you revoke?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The penalty is -20, last for 5 years, and is applied to all of your direct vassals at the time of revocation. Each revocation is tracked separately. The penalty also only applies to the ruler, so once he dies the penalty doesn't pass on to his successor.